# I'm trying to make another object move, besides from the character

Tags: movement, game-maker

I want to create a small build of a TRPG, simaler to the Fire Emblem games. What I want to do is that I want to have the cursor be able to move a 'character' to a certain location. Any help?
(I'm doing this in Game Maker)

Comment: Can you be even less precise? We cannot help you unless you explain/show us what you have tried

Comment: If you have no idea what you are doing, you should start smaller.  Look at tutorials possibly, to try to learn how to get started.  I am voting to close this question, as it is about how to get started (off topic for the site).  Come back when you have a more specific problem with your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using GML or DND?

In GML you can do something like

```
x = mouse_x
y = mouse_y
```

in the Step event.